# Is it something optional to use @WebListener when you implement a listener interface?

Tags: servlets

Why should I use this annotation @WebListener if I do this below and works?

```
public class AppListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        System.out.println("Session created!");

    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        System.out.println("Session destroyed!");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do nothing in these implement method like this:

```
public class AppListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    }
}
```

Listeners like HttpSessionListener are commonly used to make statistics about the number of people online. The general practice of the past is to combine login and exit functions .

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is that you don't need the @WebListener annotation in this case because the binding for your listener is configured in web.xml. My guess is , if you look at your web.xml file, something like this is present:

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>com.blam.AppListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

If not, then i suspect magic ...